# Setting bibliography style in footnotes with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I use `\footcite` to put the bibliography at the footnote of a book.

```
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

produces a lot of unnecessary information like:

> William H Gates and Christos H Papadimitriou. “Bounds for sorting by
>   prefix reversal”. In: Discrete Math. 27.1 (1979), pp. 47–57. ISSN:
>   0012-365X. DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012- 365X(79) 90068-2. URL:
>   http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X79900682.

All other style like:

```
\usepackage[style=nature,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

produces only a number at the footnote.

How can I have some other style like:

> W H Gates and C H Papadimitriou. “Bounds for sorting by prefix
>   reversal”. In: Discrete Math. 27.1 (1979), pp. 47–57.

?

Comment: Read the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf): section 3.3 "Standard Styles", p.65, biblatex v3.7.

Comment: As I stated above, they are of no use. All other style I tried produced only a number at the footnote!!

Comment: It appears that the 'verbose' style by default prints a lot of information (hence the name, I suppose). There are dozens of styles now. But there are also dozens of options you can use. E.g., `isbn=false`, `url=false`, `doi=false`, `eprint=false`....

Comment: Yes, it is better now. But how about the authors' name?

Answer (score 1):

The command `\footcite`  puts the citation into a footnote: the citation in a numeric style is '1' or similar, as expected. You want `\footfullcite`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Some text.\footfullcite{westfahl:space}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion i.e. \footfullcite and

Comment: @latra You've asked several 'scattergun' questions on `biblatex` without any real sense of what you are up to! I've linked elsewhere to our standard 'how to customise `biblatex` styles' guide: please use it to ask focussed question(s) on the parts of the customisation process you are struggling with!